# codeigniter works on live site but not localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, localhost

I copied my live Codeigniter project to my local machine to make development a little easier, but it's not displaying right. NO changes have been made, so I am not sure why this is happening? It almost acts like it cant read from the database, but the listings on the bottom come from a select query so I feel like thats not the case..

I am using Windows 10 IIS with PHP.

Live site: http://beta.btcbidder.com/

Localhost image: 
[image]

Comment: perhaps your localhost version does not parse shorthand php tags? Are you using <?= ?> anywhere in your script?

Comment: Are you using IIS on your "live" site?

Comment: @self, no, on the live site I am using CentOS LAMP setup

Comment: @JethroHazelhurst, you were correct about this, php.ini had this disabled and the code was littered with shorthand tags

Comment: No probs glad it worked!

Answer (score 2):

There may be something wrong with your php tags because of the raw output in your image above. This could be down to the use of shorthand php tags which are generally considered bad practice.

```
<? ?> & <?= ?>
```

Shorthand php tags are disabled on some server configurations so for this reason it is best to use a templating engine or at least use the full php markup.

Do a find and replace and replace all `<? ... ?>` or `<?= ?>` tags with the full php tags `<?php ... ?>`

Comment: True, however php short tags make your code un-shareable as it is best practice to assume your end user does not have short tags enabled.

Comment: Thanks for this. because the code is literally littered with this, I enabled shorthand codes in php.ini for now, until I can replace them all.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use .htaccess for the same

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value short_open_tag 1
</IfModule>
```